# My outrageously simple IF statement is evaluating to false... when it's undeniably true!

Tags: php, mysql, if-statement

```
if($array[$i]['positiveOrNegative'] == 'p')
```

This array value is pulled from MySQL DB, from a CHAR(1) column.  I've var_dumped both variables and BOTH return string(1) p

I have NO idea in the world why this isn't evaluating correctly, it's honestly blowing my mind.  It does work if I do `p == p`.  Also, `strcmp($array[$i]['positiveOrNegative'],p)` returns 1 (meaning they are NOT the same).  How, on earth, could this be!?

**--------UPDATE:**

Wait, I must have VarDumped badly.... now my variable is this:

- $array[$i]['positiveOrNegative']
- string(4) "p"

AND

- var_dump(p)
- string(1) "p"

How is the variable p inside MySQL a string(4) ???

**More Updates...**
Every entry in that column is a string(4), but they are all one letter (n or p).  Further, they are string(4)'s even when I insert the letter by hand with PHPMyAdmin...

Comment: @Jon - yea, I've tried that.  Take a look at my update though.  @SLaks, nope - no upper case.

Comment: @alex, hmmm.  Maybe.  My MySQL structure says that the column is  `latin1_swedish_ci`

Comment: Please try var_dump on the other characters of
$array[$i]['positiveOrNegative']

Comment: Love the question title.  Has a Buddist "Zen" feel to it: life is death, sadness is happiness, true is false...

Comment: @Jon - still string(4)'s for all variables in that column...  @Stephen, HA! thanks man. hahaha.

Comment: $x = $array[$i]['positiveOrNegative']; var_dump($x[1]); That still returns string(4)?

Comment: @Jon,   var_dump($x);  - still string(4).... I'll just change to 1's and 0's.  It's crazy though, because I have long strings describing actions all over the place, with no issue... only this time with the single character.

Comment: var_dump($x[1]); Should get the second character in the string. It could be some whitespace that the trim() function can handle.

Comment: @Jon, hmmm.  I'll test it out later.  I've replaced it with INT(1) 1 or 0 for now... dang php! ha.

Comment: what exactly is $array? what API do you use to connect php with mysql?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

have you tried printing the array out to screen to see the output?

```
print_r($array[$i]['positiveOrNegative']);
```

By doing this you will be able to see the entire contents of the array and any oddities should stick out pretty clearly.

The reason I mention this is because it may not matter exactly how the database is treating it, as long as it is persisting a value you can use.

Therefore if you check the result of your operation visually to make sure there is nothing odd happening you might be able to format that database output before doing your conditional comparison.

Comment: @Jesse I just updated the question take a look.  My variable returns string(4) for just the letter p... how is this possible?  any way to correct it?

Comment: @Shackrock Is your question MySQL or PHP related, I have significantly more experience with PHP than the MySQL specifics?  If you want to know MySQL semantics, the only guess I have to offer is that MySQL treats your 'p' like a string(4) because that is its minimum for the string datatype? Kind of like how C++ compilers make four boolean values when you only request one, and hold the others in reserve.

Comment: @Jesse - well I really don't care about it in MySQL honestly... I just need the variable to be represented correctly by the time it hits the comparison -> so is there some PHP operation I can perform on the variable to get it back to string(1) ?     BTW, it's CHAR(1) in the DB already, it shouldn't be string(4) to my knowledge...

Comment: @Shackrock  PHP is weakly typed so it should interpret and assign the datatype for you when you assign it to a variable.  Perhaps try saving that element to a local variable and then doing the comparison.  I had a friend have a similar problem with the "bit" datatype in MsSQL, I'm thinking its just a conversion issue which is why I think that this PHP manual entry might help? [link]http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strcmp.php , that or alex might be right and you have a strange encoding of character set issue...

Comment: @Jesse, I was wishing for you.. haha.  Nope, no luck.  Same result.  This just seems so crazy to me.  Is there some string operation I can use?

Comment: @Shackrock I have an idea, since your column is named "positiveOrNegative" can I assume this is a boolean type situation of "true/false"? if so, instead of using a character to represent that go with the tried and tested method of 0 for false and 1  true?  This may get rid of this really odd behavior... I know that it would require a bit of redesign on your part.. and I wonder if you can change the Db schema or not, but maybe use an integer instead of a char/string

Comment: @Jesse, I was hoping to avoid that, it's a lot of rework...  I just tried the utf8_decode and ENcode functions, no luck... I might be going to 1/0 afterall.

Comment: @Shackrock bummer dude, I'm stumped, obviously there are three invisible characters in the string you return from the array, something is definitely strange.  Its almost like when you save your string the database makes it "   p" instead of "p".  ~"The beatings will continue until morale improves"

Comment: @Shackrock Here is a possibly relevant S.O. post [link] http://stackoverflow.com/questions/765255/php-mysql-insert-data-into-database-character-set-problem  , I'm still searching for MySQL documentation on character storing procedures.

Comment: So odd!  I'll play around with it later, unfortunately I have to move on at the moment, ha!  Thanks for the tip though, 1/0 is working fine.

Comment: @Shackrock glad to hear 1/0 is working.  Numbers don't have weird types, they are pretty straightforward, I use PHP constants with the define() method that evaluate out to an integer, it makes the comparisons really easy to do because it comes back to the native machine language: MATH.  Good luck and god speed in your journey.

Comment: @Jesse moving up in the world :D

Answer (score 1):

Echo it out and run it through `od -c`. This will tell you exactly what PHP has in the variable. From there you can scrub the data, and perhaps fix the process that is inserting this malformed data in the first place.

```
php somescript.php | od -c
```

Answer (score 0):

If the string really has 4 bytes try doing to following so we can further examine the contents:

```
print_r(array_map('ord', str_split($array[$i]['positiveOrNegative'])));
```